# How to implement commiting peer in hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyperledger fabric and I am currently studying it for one of my project. Project needs implementation of both endorsing peer as well as commiting peer. Till now I am able to run test network and add a new endorsing peer to running network. But I don't know how implement( in Java) commiting peer in hyperledger fabric network. Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`committing peer` is a peer that maintains the ledger and chaincode, and basically **all peers** are `committing peers`.

See the official documentation below

- [fabric/v2.2/Types of peers](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/network/network.html?highlight=committing#types-of-peers)
  **Every peer node** in a channel is a `committing peer`.
  It receives blocks of generated transactions, which are subsequently validated before they are committed to the peer node’s copy of the ledger as an append operation.

In other words, peer, whether endorsing or not, plays the role of a committing peer.

### [image]

If you want to use a specific peer as a committing peer, set it in the connection-profile configure of `fabric-sdk`.
(In this case peer used only as a committing peer, the peer has an endorsing function, but simply does not request endorsing.)

- [fabric-sdk/v2.2/sample/connection-profile](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/developapps/connectionprofile.html#sample) `endorsingPeer: false`

```
...
82:       peer3.magnetocorp.example.com:
83:         endorsingPeer: false
84:         chaincodeQuery: false
85:         ledgerQuery: true
86:         eventSource: true
...
```

---

- [P.S] the peer type (committer, endorser) and role (leader, anchor) are different, so don't get confused.